# Throwing 8 sided dice 3 times with the sum of the throws being 6, whats the probability that the first throw was 3?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, dice

We already threw the 8 sided dice 3 times. The sum of these 3 throws was 6. Whats the probability that in our first throw we got 3?

I am a little lost on this one, but I would probably do it something like this:

3 _ _ -> 3 2 1 | 3 1 2  which is the 2 ways that we are trying to find the probability of happening. All possible ways to get sum of 6 would be: _ _ _ -> 2 2 2 -> 2 3 1 | 2 1 3 | 1 2 3 | 1 3 2 | 3 2 1 | 3 1 2 | 4 1 1 | 1 4 1 | 1 1 4. So is the probability 2/10?

Comment: The answer should be $\frac{2}{7}$, you counted the number of possible ways wrongly.

Comment: What are the values on this $8$-sided die??? Sounds to me like there should be at least $8$ distinct values. Not that it makes any difference from a $6$-sided die in the context of this question, but it sure as hell makes a difference with regards to your bizarre way of answering it, where you chose to ignore the value $4$. If this value is not present on the die, then I think you should care to mention that!!!

Comment: @barakmanos forgot about the 4. :b The thing is, I think this way of solving it is wrong, because it is conditional probability.

Comment: @Mykybo: You are now (after your fix) implicitly applying conditional probability (you can divide both the numerator and the denominator by $8^3$, but you'd get the same result).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is conditional probability.
If $A$ is the event that the first throw was $3$ and $B$ is the event that the sum is $6$, then you are looking for $P(A|B)$.

Using [Bayes' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem):

$$ P(A|B) = \frac{P(A)P(B|A)}{P(B)}$$

$$P(A) = \frac{1}{8}$$

$$P(B|A) = P(sum\quad of\quad two\quad throws\quad is\quad 3) = \frac{2}{64}$$

$$P(B) = \frac{10}{512}$$

Thus

$$P(A|B) = \frac{2}{10} = \frac{1}{5}$$

Answer (score 2):

The first roll is $3$ in $2$ out of $10$ cases (of the sum of $3$ rolls being $6$):

- $1,1,4$
- $1,2,3$
- $1,3,2$
- $1,4,1$
- $2,1,3$
- $2,2,2$
- $2,3,1$
- $\color\red{3,1,2}$
- $\color\red{3,2,1}$
- $4,1,1$

So the probability is $\dfrac{2}{10}$

Comment: Are you sure this is the way to solve it? Isn't it a conditional probability?

Comment: @Mykybo: By taking into account only the cases of the condition (the sum of $3$ rolls being $6$), I have effectively applied conditional probability. By editing your question and adding all the cases that I've mentioned above, you have effectively made my answer obsolete!

Answer (score 1):

You've missed the combinations 4 1 1, 1 4 1, 1 1 4
There'll be a total of 10 combinations with seven that you've mentioned
Thus the probability will be 2/10